# query takes too long with function

Tags: sql, t-sql

Executing my current query takes 1:16 minutes. That is way too long. Here is how my query looks like atm:

```
SELECT
[plugin.tickets].[Ticket].Id,
[plugin.tickets].[Ticket].Title,
[plugin.tickets].[Ticket].Created,
[plugin.tickets].[Ticket].StartProgress,
[dbo].[worktime]([plugin.tickets].[Ticket].Created, GetDate()) AS OpenstaandeTijdInUren,
[plugin.tickets].[Ticket].firstresponse,
DATEDIFF(HOUR, [plugin.tickets].[Ticket].Created, [plugin.tickets].[Ticket].FirstResponse) AS ReactietijdInUren,
[plugin.tickets].[Ticket].Status,
[plugin.tickets].[Ticket].Priority,
DATEDIFF (MINUTE, [plugin.tickets].[Ticket].Created, [plugin.tickets].[Ticket].EndProgress) as OplostijdTicketInUren
FROM [plugin.tickets].[Ticket]
WHERE [dbo].[worktime]([plugin.tickets].[Ticket].Created, GetDate()) >= 1
    AND ([plugin.tickets].[Ticket].status <= 2)
ORDER BY [plugin.tickets].[Ticket].id
```

In the query there is a function I use which I made. The function calculates the difference in hours between two dates. For calculating the time excluding holidays I have made a table which contains the holidays for oncoming 10 years. Most likely thats why it is taking so long for the query to execute, because for every row it checks of the date contains same date as the holiday table. But I am not sure what the solution for this problem is?

Here is my function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[WorkTime]
(@StartDate DATETIME, @FinishDate DATETIME)
RETURNS BIGINT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Temp BIGINT
    SET @Temp = 0
    DECLARE @FirstDay DATE
    SET @FirstDay = CONVERT(DATE, @StartDate, 112)
    DECLARE @LastDay DATE
    SET @LastDay = CONVERT(DATE, @FinishDate, 112)
    DECLARE @StartTime TIME
    SET @StartTime = CONVERT(TIME, @StartDate)
    DECLARE @FinishTime TIME
    SET @FinishTime = CONVERT(TIME, @FinishDate)
    DECLARE @WorkStart TIME
    SET @WorkStart = '08:00'
    DECLARE @WorkFinish TIME
    SET @WorkFinish = '18:00'
    DECLARE @DailyWorkTime BIGINT
    SET @DailyWorkTime = DATEDIFF(HOUR, @WorkStart, @WorkFinish)
    IF (@StartTime<@WorkStart)
    BEGIN
        SET @StartTime = @WorkStart
    END
    IF (@FinishTime>@WorkFinish)
    BEGIN
        SET @FinishTime=@WorkFinish
    END
    IF (@FinishTime<@WorkStart)
    BEGIN
        SET @FinishTime=@WorkStart
    END
    IF (@StartTime>@WorkFinish)
    BEGIN
        SET @StartTime = @WorkFinish
    END
    DECLARE @CurrentDate DATE
    SET @CurrentDate = @FirstDay
    DECLARE @LastDate DATE
    SET @LastDate = @LastDay
    WHILE(@CurrentDate<=@LastDate)
    BEGIN     
        IF
             (DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate)!=1 AND DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate)!=7)
                 AND @CurrentDate NOT IN 
                     (SELECT Datum_feestdag FROM Feestdagen)
             BEGIN
                 IF (@CurrentDate!=@FirstDay) AND (@CurrentDate!=@LastDay)
                 BEGIN
                 SET @Temp = @Temp + @DailyWorkTime
            END
            --IF it starts at startdate and it finishes not this date find diff between work finish and start as hours
            ELSE IF (@CurrentDate=@FirstDay) AND (@CurrentDate!=@LastDay)
            BEGIN
                SET @Temp = @Temp + DATEDIFF(HOUR, @StartTime, @WorkFinish)
            END
            ELSE IF (@CurrentDate!=@FirstDay) AND (@CurrentDate=@LastDay)
            BEGIN
                SET @Temp = @Temp + DATEDIFF(HOUR, @WorkStart, @FinishTime)
            END
            --IF it starts and finishes in the same date
            ELSE IF (@CurrentDate=@FirstDay) AND (@CurrentDate=@LastDay)
            BEGIN
                SET @Temp = DATEDIFF(HOUR, @StartTime, @FinishTime)
            END
        END
        SET @CurrentDate = DATEADD(day, 1, @CurrentDate)
    END

    -- Return the result of the function

    IF @Temp < 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Temp = 0
    END
    RETURN @Temp
END
```

How can I run my query without using the function in the query? I have tried many things like indexing but it even takes longer with indexes.
Please help me guys, and keep in mind I am a newbie with sql etc.

Thanks alot, Shabby

Comment: Did you a try a query plan for your query and for your function alone ? Also I think this IF statement can need a lot of performance : `AND @CurrentDate NOT IN (SELECT Datum_feestdag FROM Feestdagen)`

Comment: How many rows are in the table `ticket`?  And how many of those have `status <= 2`?  How long does the function take to run on just one row? Can you write the function in reverse *(to be like `date_add()` rather than `date_diff()`)*?

Comment: @MatBailie Hi, thanks for your reply. When I run it on just one row it gives me instantly output. The column "ticket" contains 506 rows with the where clause. I tried to write the function as you said but getting errors like: "Argument data type is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function."

Comment: You didn't answer all the parts of my questions ;) Also, my last point was to write a whole new version of your function, from scratch, that allows you to add or subtract working hours to a date, instead of counting the the bunlver of working hours between two dates.  (Also nothing runs instantly, it must take some number of milliseconds or microseconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course that will be slow. It has to apply that function to every single row in the table. It can't use indexes to minimise the amount of rows it has to process.

A crude option would be to "manually" limit the number of rows it has to process. Such as knowing that 1 hour of work time back from "now" must be at least 1 hour ago, and maybe you could even "know" tickets never get to be more than 10 days old?

Now you can have...

```
WHERE
        [plugin.tickets].[Ticket].Created >= DATEADD(DAY , -10, GETDATE())
    AND [plugin.tickets].[Ticket].Created <  DATEADD(Hour, -1 , GETDATE())
    AND [plugin.tickets].[Ticket].status <= 2
    AND [dbo].[worktime]([plugin.tickets].[Ticket].Created, GetDate()) >= 1
```

The first three conditions can then be quickly solved with an index *(create the index on `(status, created)`, as a single compound index)*, reducing the number of records that have to be parsed through your function.

Even better, write a dateadd function...

```
WHERE
        [plugin.tickets].[Ticket].status  <= 2
    AND [plugin.tickets].[Ticket].created <= [dbo].[add_worktime]('HOUR', -1, GetDate())
```

Now your function is only called ONCE *(with GETDATE() as the input)* rather than repeatedly for every row. And the result of it can be used against the same index as mentioned before.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it helped my query a lot. It is now taking 28 secs instead of 1.28 minute. I think for now it is good enough since I am using it hourly for updating my report. Thanks alot

Comment: @shabby : On my break I wrote this for you...  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b634fe23d5c6d09a47daebab9fb5bb23

Comment: You are a boss!! I am going to check it after my break:P You will hear from me! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I'm 100% sure that your query is slow because of that :

```
WHILE(@CurrentDate<=@LastDate)
    BEGIN     
        IF
             (DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate)!=1 AND DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate)!=7)
                 AND @CurrentDate NOT IN 
                     (SELECT Datum_feestdag FROM Feestdagen)
```

So for improve this, I an suggest you to create an index on `Datum_feestdag` in `Feestdagen` and to write a sargeable query like.

```
IF (DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate)!=1 AND DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate)!=7)
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT Datum_feestdag 
                        FROM Feestdagen
                        WHERE @CurrentDate = Datum_feestdag)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I have made a clustered index on Datum_feestdag but do I keep the WHILE statement in my function? Because it doesn't change the speed of the query still...

Comment: Can you try to have the query plan ? Print your screen and give it us. I'm curious to see it